# Adding class to next element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having html like this:

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="radio" class="radio">
        <label>Text</label>
        <input type="radio" class="radio">
        <label>Type</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now I need to apply a class to each label immediate after each `<input type="radio">`.

I am using jquery like this:

```
if($('input').hasClass('radio')){
    $(this).next().addClass('radio-url');
}
```

I am trying to add class 'radio-url' to each `<label>` immediately after radio tag.
What mistake have I did in this?

Comment: Use `$('.radio').next('label').addClass('radio-url');` - I'm guessing you don't have the correct context of `this`, which is why your code doesn't work - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NpQJh/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
$('input[type="radio"]').siblings('label').addClass('radio-url');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Nkvvc/1/)

Or

```
$('input[type="radio"]').next('label').addClass('radio-url');
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/Nkvvc/2/)

Comment: You probably want to use `.next()` because `siblings()` will target *all* the labels, not just the one.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(':radio').next().addClass('radio-url');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/A5PH7/2)** (I threw a text input in there so you can see that it works on only radio inputs)

Answer (score 1):

You can use next() function

```
 $("input:radio").next('label').addClass("radio-url");`
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't directly answer your question!

I believe that your label should have the *for* attribute so that the label is associated with the radio button. This allows the user:

1. To check the radio button by clicking the label!
2. If the input type is text, clicking the label focuses the text input
3. For accessibility reasons

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" id="text"></input>
    <label for="text">Text</label>
    <input type="radio" class="radio" id="type"></input>
    <label for="type">Type</label>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

Search the label using the radio element's ID.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
    var radioId = $(this).attr("id");
    $("label[for='" + radioId + "']").addClass('radio-url');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/78zAB/

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all radio buttons:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
    $(this).next().addClass('radio-url');
});
```

**Or**

```
$("input[type='radio'] + label").addClass('radio-url')
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwuCd/1/)

[**Example 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwuCd/3/)

Comment: The `if` statement is probably not needed here, nor is it even correct.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yeah Thanks for pointing out! forgot to remove :)

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HervL/)

```
$('input.radio').each(function () {
    $(this).next().addClass('radio-url');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS element+element selector:

```
$('input:radio + label').addClass('theClass')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ttnUU/

Answer (score 0):

Works optimal

```
$('input[type=radio]').next('label').addClass('radio-url');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q76FJ/

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as an answer as all of the others are using the incorrect selector, or don't specify the `label` in `next()`:

```
$('input.radio').next('label').addClass('radio-url');
```

.. which will add the class `radio-url` to all `label` elements which come immediately after an `input` with the class `radio`